# The name 'inputLength' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've spent some time on this password generator but I'm simply too daft to make it work!

I've got an input and an output textbox with generated usernames and passwords.

The problem is the third textbox, **"inputLength"** where I want the user to decide how long the passwords are going to be, in GeneratePassword()

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] newRow = new char[] { '\r', '\n' };
    string[] name = input.Text.Split(newRow, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
    {
        result += string.Format("{0}{1} # {2}\r\n",name[i].Substring(0, 3), i, GeneratePassword());
    }
    output.Text = result;
}

private static string GeneratePassword()
{
    int passwordLength = Int32.Parse(inputLength.Text);
    string result = "";
    string allowedChars = "1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM";
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
    {
        result += allowedChars[random.Next(allowedChars.Length)].ToString();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    return result;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Probably you don't have a local variable as `inputLength` in your `GeneratePassword` method. Maybe you wanna `int i = 0; i < passwordLength ; i++` instead?

Comment: `i < passwordLength`  rather than `i < inputLength` and make `GeneratePassword` non-static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this code is in a Windows Forms application, as you've written code for a button Event Handler (`button1_Click`), which is then calling a *static* method called `GeneratePassword`.

The issue is that the **static** `GeneratePassword` method is attempting to access the instance member `inputLength`, which it cannot do. You have two choices:

1. Make `GeneratePassword` an instance member (remove the `static`) so it can access the `inputLength` instance member.
2. Pass the value(s) from `inputLength` into `GeneratePassword`, e.g.:

   `private static string GeneratePassword(string inputLength)`

Which you'd then call like:

```
result += string.Format("{0}{1} # {2}\r\n",name[i].Substring(0, 3), i, GeneratePassword(inputLength.Text));
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because `GeneratePassword` is static and can only access static members and methods.
`inputLenght` is a `TextBox` and is member of your form so `GeneratePassword` can not access it.

Simply remove static from `GeneratePassword` definition or pass `inputLength.Text` as a parameter to `GeneratePassword` function.

Comment: and that, dear children, is why it's a good idea to at least consider using the `this` keyword.